# Defining a function that includes only part of a with statement

Tags: python, with-statement, function

I am trying to define a function so that it includes only part of a with statement. For example, it would include the section cut off by #####.

```
#####

with open(filename,'r') as fh:

    contentall = fh.read().replace('\n', '')

    contentall = contentall.upper()

    print contentall

#####

    i = contentall.count(">")

    print i
```

My problem is that there is still some stuff in the `with` statement that I don't want in my function. Can this be done without creating two different `with` statements?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do. Do you perhaps want to just return `contentall` from the function?

Comment: Why don't you just have a function that does the opening, replacing and uppering then returns the result. Then you can do your count and print contentall

Comment: Technically, only the line that reads from `fh` needs to be in the body of the `with` statement. The rest have the same behavior in or after.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes I just want to print `contentall` from the function but I want to do other stuff outside of the function but still in the same with statement

Comment: @chepner I just used example code that doesn't really particularly apply to the question, but thank you.

Comment: @owen79 the question was not about the particular code that I used as an example, but more about the concept of with statements. In actuality, my real code does not include `print contentall` I just put that there for testing reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You could pass the context manager to the second function as a parameter, but you can't share a context manager between two function definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Could you not do this

```
def getContent(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as fh:
        contentall = fh.read().replace('\n', '')
        contentall = contentall.upper()
    return contentall

contentall = getContent(filename)
print contentall
i = contentall.count(">")
print i
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable to enable or disable the counting behaviour:

```
def contentFunc(filename, countBool):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
        contentall = fh.read().replace('\n',' ').upper()
        print contentall
        if countBool == True:
            print contentall.count(">")
```